# Slice_max in the tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the function slice_max from dplyr 1.0.0, but I keep getting the error "could not find function "slice_max". I have removed and reinstalled dplyr but still cannot access the function. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this? I'm using R Studio with R 3.6.2.

Comment: slice_max() isn't in the standard dplyr package. It is found in the hadley/dplyr package here https://rdrr.io/github/hadley/dplyr/man/slice.html.  Never used it so I cannot comment more.

Comment: That will be because it is in the development version of dplyr. If you want to use the fucntion you need to download the development version of dplyr with `install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("hadley/dplyr")`

Comment: I know there was a post from Hadley in early March talking about a longer timeline for the rollout of new functions, but it looks like e.g. slice_max has already been incorporated into the tidyverse: https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dplyr/man/slice.html. If it's not, though, I guess that's the end of this road for me - I can't access GitHub on the restricted computer I'm on.

Answer (score 4):

slice_max() and slice_min() are not available in dplyr and tydiverse for R version 3.6.2
To use these functions, you need to update R to version 4.0.4, and then reinstall dplyr and tydiverse. They should work fine.